# Convert nested list into DataFrame of 3 columns

Tags: python-3.x

I have a nested list (data).

> print(data)

M1A
Not assigned
Not assigned

M2A
Not assigned
Not assigned

M3A
North York
Parkwoods

M4A
North York
Victoria Village

.
.
.

When I have print(data[0]), I got the first element of each row instead of the first row.

> print(data[0])

M
N
N
M
N
N
M
N
P
M
N
V
.
.
.

Why does this happen?
And how to convert this nested list into DataFrame of 3 columns.
col1   col2           col3
M1A    Not assigned  Not assigned
...

Comment: could You give us some more info , and fix the formating ? I mean, how You create this Data Frame, how looks the data at the begining ? ....

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to scrape a table from html using BeautifulSoup and that was the outcome. It turned out that I do not need it at all and I just can use pd.read_html. That worked very well.